# Bluetooth audio device connected but can't select it as output device

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 23.04, bluez, pipewire

In Gnome's Bluetooth settings, I can connect to my earbuds. However, despite seeing that they are in [Connected] state in the GUI, and "paired" via `bluetoothctl info`[1], I cannot select them as an output device. I was able work around this manually[2] in the terminal after which the device was available to select as an output device in Gnome's Sound settings. However, this doesn't work reliably (I cannot reproduce this workaround right now), and this obviously shouldn't be the normal way for users to select a bluetooth output device.

Is this expected behavior? Is this a bug? Which project should it be filed against: bluez, pipewire, gnome, or the kernel?

[1]

```
bluetoothctl info         
Device 28:6F:40:AB:1B:5C (public)
    Name: JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE
    Alias: JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE
    Class: 0x00240404
    Icon: audio-headset
    Paired: yes
    Bonded: yes
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Amazon.com Services, Inc. (0000fe03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Google                    (0000fe2c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (65786365-6c70-6f69-6e74-2e636f6d0000)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (66666666-6666-6666-6666-666666666666)
    ServiceData Key: 0000fe2c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    ServiceData Value:
  00 40 80 d0 28 10 34 7f 64 28                    .@..(.4.d(      
    RSSI: -54
    TxPower: -15
```

[2]

```
bluetoothctl scan on
# Find the device's address
bluetoothctl connect <address>
# Then the device became visible as an endpoint
```

[3] bluetooth controller info

```
Controller A8:BB:CF:20:9F:AF (public)
    Name: guest
    Alias: guest
    Class: 0x007c010c
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: no
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
    Pairable: no
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0542
    Discovering: no
    Roles: central
    Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
    SupportedInstances: 0x05 (5)
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name
```

System Info

```
Ubuntu Release: Lunar Lobster
Bluez Version: 5.66-0ubuntu1
Pipewire Version: 0.3.65-3
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-26-generic
Bluetooth endpoint: JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue on Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar (with pipewire), but your manual solution does not seem to be a solution.

Anyways, I tried many things. But essentially what worked for me is the following.

`sudo apt --reinstall install pipewire-media-session`

It killed my Ubuntu desktop, so I did in text:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Then I reinitialized some more pipewire related things:

`systemctl --user enable --now pipewire && systemctl --user enable --now wireplumber &&  systemctl --user enable --now pipewire-pulse`

(I got a weird error saying that wireplumber was not installed, so I installed it `sudo apt install wireplumber` and re-ran the previous command).

My Sony MX5 finally started to function fully.
[Screenshot: Sony MX5 on Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yLR7.png)